# Bound on expectation, not a really simple process, circumvent using Itō's lemma?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

Assume that $H_t$ is a progressively measurable process such that with probability one $|H_t| \le k$ for all $t$. Let$$Z_t = \int_0^t H_s\,dB_s.$$How do I see that for all $s < t$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, that$$\textbf{E}[\text{exp}\{\lambda(Z_t - Z_s)\}] \le \text{exp}\left\{{{k^2\lambda^2}\over2}(t - s)\right\}?$$I know how to show this using Itō's lemma, but I was wondering if anyone could supply a proof or a reference to one that does not use it. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use Itô?  It's one of the most fundamental tools there is for dealing with stochastic integrals and semimartingales.

Comment: By time change and reflection principle you easily get a bound which is more than once but less than twice your right hand side. I do not know how to improve this argument to the (correct) bound that you asked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove it going back to the definition of the stochastic integral. If $H$ is constant on the interval $[s,t)$ then conditionally to $\mathcal F_s$ (the underlying filtration at time $s$), $Z_t-Z_s$ is a centerer gaussian with variance $H_s^2 (t-s)$, and hence we have $$\textbf{E}[\text{exp}\{\lambda(Z_t - Z_s)\} | \mathcal F_s] =\text{exp}\left\{{{H_s^2 \lambda^2}\over 2}(t - s)\right\} \le \text{exp}\left\{{{k^2\lambda^2}\over2}(t - s)\right\}.$$
If $H_s$ is a simple process (ie piecewise constant), then the same inequality $\textbf{E}[\text{exp}\{\lambda(Z_t - Z_s)\} | \mathcal F_s]  \le \text{exp}\left\{{{k^2\lambda^2}\over2}(t - s)\right\}$ holds by applying the preceding on each interval on which $H$ is constant. It therefore holds for every progressively measurable process by density of the simple processes.

Comment: Exponential moments might not be continuous for the L^2 topology, but (by Fatou's lemma) they are lower semicontinuous, which is enough here.

Comment: Sorry, confused limsup and liminf.